# Nvim-lspconfig sorting diagnostics floating windows

Tags: neovim, lsp

Is there a way to raise floating windows by their type in nvim-lspconfig?
Like in this situation I would like to see the documentation window above the errors window.

[image: lspconfig-sort-windows]

Many thanks in advance.